# GCDAsyncUdpSocket send multiple time the same data

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, udp

In my app I've to connect to a server using UDP. So I included this library: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket. My code works as follow:

1. To create the socket by using the following code:

```
private func setupSocket() {
    outSocket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket.init(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    outSocket.setIPv4Enabled(true)
    outSocket.setIPv6Enabled(false)
    do {
       try outSocket.connect(toHost:ip ?? "", onPort: port ?? 0)
    } catch {
       outSocket.close()
    }
    do {
       try outSocket.beginReceiving()
    } catch {
       outSocket.close()
    }
}
```

2 .Then in the delegate `public func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didConnectToAddress address: Data)`I send the first packet to the server as follow:

```
public func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didConnectToAddress address: Data) {
    outSocket.send(self.generatePacket(), withTimeout: 10, tag: 0)
}
```

In which the method `generatePacket()`is common for all packet I've to send (I distinguish between the packet but using an enum).

After sending the first packet in the delegate `public func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didReceive data: Data, fromAddress address: Data, withFilterContext filterContext: Any?)` I parse the response and I send the second packet by using this code:

```
public func udpSocket(_ sock: GCDAsyncUdpSocket, didReceive data: Data, fromAddress address: Data, withFilterContext filterContext: Any?) {
    print("ANSWER: \(data.hexEncodedString(options: .upperCase))")
    switch actualOperation {
    case .FIRST_PACKET:
        actualOperation = .SECOND_PACKET
        outSocket.send(self.generatePacket(), withTimeout: 10, tag: 0)
        break
    default:
        let packetData = data.subdata(in: 23..<data.count)
        if (packetData.count != 3) {
            let dt = packetData.subdata(in: 0..<(packetData.count - 2))
            self.delegate?.workInProgress(actualStatus: String(decoding: dt.subdata(in: 3..<dt.count), as: UTF8.self))
        } else {
            self.delegate?.workCompleted()
            outSocket.close()
        }
        break
    }
}
```

When I try to run the app with this code I've some problem, because sometimes the content of the socket will be not clear. For example the first packet is ended twice and it can produce an app crash.
The first packet is the follow:

`32 31 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 35 36 37`

and the answer should be:

`32 31 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 35 36 37`

When I take a look by using Wireshark I've the following situation:

[image]

As you can see the packet number 538 and 539 are the same... If I use the code written in `didReceive` delegate it can crash because the response packet can be < 23 (packet number 540 and 541).
I hope you understand what's my problem. So how I can clean the content of the socket after I received the response to the first packet?

Thank you

**EDIT:
I got much information to understand what's happening**

This is the stack of the packet copied from Xcode console:

```
REQUEST PKT: 323035303030303130303030313030303030353734
ANSWER PKT: 323130303030303130303030313030303030353734

REQUEST PKT: 323031303030303130303030313030303030353735002FA1B045303030303030313030FF20202020202031302020202020202031FF0030303030303031303000000000005E1B
ANSWER PKT: 323130303030303130303030313030303030353734
```

As you can see the REQUEST PKT is different but the ANSWER PKT are the same...

For sure if I send the second packet

`32 30 31 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 35 37 35 00 2F A1 B0 45 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 FF 20 20 20 20 20 20 31 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 31 FF 00 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 00 00 00 00 00 5E 1B`

the answer should be:

`32 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 35 37 37 00 18 a8 00 13 50 61 67 61 6d 65 6e 74 6f 0d 0a 45 55 52 20 31 2c 30 30 ba 60`

but I receive multiple times this packet:

`32 31 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 35 36 37`

It seems that the content of the socket isn't clean and the server still receive the packet `32 31 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 35 36 37` instead of `32 30 31 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 30 30 30 35 37 35 00 2F A1 B0 45 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 FF 20 20 20 20 20 20 31 30 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 31 FF 00 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 30 00 00 00 00 00 5E 1B`

**Edit for Paulw11**

I'm sure that the code to generate the packet is called only twice (one from `didConnectToAddress` and the second from `didReceive`). So I really think that the content of the socket isn't clean when I try to send the second packet from `didReceive`.
To have much information I post here the code I made to create the 2 packets:

```
private func generatePacket() -> Data {
    var data = Data()
    switch actualOperation {
    case .FIRST_PACKET:
        data.append(self.generateHeader())
        break
    case .SECOND_PACKET:
        data.append(self.generateHeader())
        data.append(self.generateBody())
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    print("REQUEST PKT: \(data.hexEncodedString(options: .upperCase))")
    return data
}

private func generateHeader() -> Data {
    var data = Data()
    switch actualOperation {
    case .FIRST_PACKET:
        data.append(TransportProtocol.pingFromPosToClient, count: TransportProtocol.pingFromPosToClient.count)
        break
    case .SECOND_PACKET:
        data.append(TransportProtocol.messageFromPosToClient, count: TransportProtocol.messageFromPosToClient.count)
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    data.append(Constant.nodeId, count: Constant.nodeId.count)
    data.append(Constant.portId, count: Constant.portId.count)
    data.append(Constant.groupId, count: Constant.groupId.count)
    data.append(self.generateTransmissionId())
    return data
}
private func generateTransmissionId() -> Data {
    var data = Data()
    if let transId = String(format: "%05ld", transmissionID).data(using: .utf8) {
        data.append(transId)
        transmissionID += 1
        if (transmissionID > 99999) {
            transmissionID = 1
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(transmissionID, forKey: "TransmissionID")
    }
    return data
}
private func generateBodyForPayment() -> Data {
    var data = Data()
    data.append(self.getPacketLength())
    data.append(CommandsPosToClient.authRequest, count: 1)
    data.append(OperationTypePosToClient.opPayment, count: 1)
    switch currency {
    case .DANISH_KRONE:
        data.append(CurrencyCode.danishKrone, count: 1)
        break
    case .EURO:
        data.append(CurrencyCode.euro, count: 1)
        break
    case .SWISS_FRANC:
        data.append(CurrencyCode.swissFranc, count: 1)
        break
    case .CZECH_KORUNA:
        data.append(CurrencyCode.czechKoruna, count: 1)
        break
    case .UK_POUND:
        data.append(CurrencyCode.ukPound, count: 1)
        break
    case .US_DOLLAR:
        data.append(CurrencyCode.usDollar, count: 1)
        break
    case .KUWAITI_DINAR:
        data.append(CurrencyCode.kuwaitiDinar, count: 1)
        break
    case .POLISH_ZLOTY:
        data.append(CurrencyCode.polishZloty, count: 1)
        break
    case .HUNGARIAN_FLORINT:
        data.append(CurrencyCode.hungarianFlorint, count: 1)
        break
    default:
        data.append(CurrencyCode.euro, count: 1)
        break
    }
    let amount = Int(toPay * 100)
    if let amountToPay = String(format: "%09ld", amount).data(using: .utf8) {
        data.append(amountToPay)
    }
    data.append(Constant.manTrans, count: Constant.manTrans.count)
    //ID cassiere 8 byte
    if let idEmp = "\(idEmployee ?? 0)".paddingToLeft(upTo: 8).data(using: .utf8) {
        data.append(idEmp)
    }
    //Numero scontrino 8 byte
    if let billNmb = "\(billNumber ?? 0)".paddingToLeft(upTo: 8).data(using: .utf8) {
        data.append(billNmb)
    }
    data.append(Constant.plugIn, count: Constant.plugIn.count)
    data.append(Constant.voidField, count: Constant.voidField.count)
    if let amountToPay = String(format: "%09ld", amount).data(using: .utf8) {
        data.append(amountToPay)
    }
    data.append(Constant.voidField, count: Constant.voidField.count)
    data.append(Constant.voidField, count: Constant.voidField.count)
    data.append(Constant.voidField, count: Constant.voidField.count)
    //TODO: Extra data
    data.append(Constant.voidField, count: Constant.voidField.count)
    data.append(Constant.voidField, count: Constant.voidField.count)

    if let crcData = self.crc16(data.bytes) {
        data.append(crcData)
    }
    return data
}
private func getPacketLength() -> Data {
    var data = Data()
    var packetLength = 2
    packetLength += 1 //Lunghezza del comando --> sempre 1 byte
    packetLength += 1 //Lunghezza dell'operazione --> sempre 1 byte
    switch actualOperation {
    case .SECOND_PACKET:
        packetLength += 1 //Lunghezza della valuta
        packetLength += 9 //Lunghezza dell'importo
        packetLength += 1 //Lunghezza della tipologia della transazione
        packetLength += 8 //Lunghezza del campo dedicato all'ID del cassiere
        packetLength += 8 //Lunghezza del campo dedicato al numero dello scontrino
        packetLength += 1 //Lunghezza di plug-in
        packetLength += 1 //Lunghezza di RFU
        packetLength += 9 //Lunghezza del totale
        packetLength += 1 //Lunghezza di Track 1
        packetLength += 1 //Lunghezza di Track 2
        packetLength += 1 //Lunghezza di Track 3
        packetLength += 1 //Lunghezza di Extra data length
        packetLength += 1 //Lunghezza di Extra data
        break
    default:
        break
    }

    var value = UInt16(littleEndian: UInt16(packetLength))
    var array = withUnsafeBytes(of: &value) { Array($0) }
    array.reverse()
    for var byte in array {
        data.append(Data(bytes: &byte, count: 1))
    }
    return data
}
private func crc16(_ data: [UInt8]) -> Data? {
    guard !data.isEmpty else {
        print("data is empty")
        return nil
    }
    let polynomial: UInt16 = 0xA001
    var accumulator: UInt16 = 0
    for byte in data {
        var tempByte = UInt16(byte)
        for _ in 0 ..< 8 {
            let temp1 = accumulator & 0x0001
            accumulator = accumulator >> 1
            let temp2 = tempByte & 0x0001
            tempByte = tempByte >> 1
            if (temp1 ^ temp2) == 1 {
                accumulator = accumulator ^ polynomial
            }
        }
    }
    var data = Data()
    var value = UInt16(bigEndian: accumulator)
    var array = withUnsafeBytes(of: &value) { Array($0) }
    array.reverse()
    for var byte in array {
        data.append(Data(bytes: &byte, count: 1))
    }
    return data
}
```

Comment: If wireshark shows the same packet was sent twice then your code sent it twice. Regardless, you should fix your code so that it doesn't crash. Don't make assumptions about data you receive from the network. Check the size

Comment: @Paulw11: I added much information to the question. I hope that I answered you.

Comment: Well, either GCDAsyncSocket has a bug (not impossible,  but it is used in thousands of apps). Or your code has a bug. What seems more likely? You should also look at a Apple's `NWConnection` rather than using an external framework.

Comment: I post all the code I made to create the packet, I hope it can be useful to understand whats' wrong.
For sure I saw that sometimes my code works perfectly sometimes has this problem: there are something that I'm missing about UDP connection?

Comment: @Paulw11: I can't use `NWConnection` because this class is compatible only with iOS 12 + and my app it's compatible with iOS 11... So really no idea what to do and how to solve this issue...